# Sharepoint 2013 New Web application, site collection does not work

Tags: web-applications, sharepoint-2013, sitecollection

I am a beginner at sharepoint, so sorry if the question is very simple. I have searched a lot but could not find the answer. 
I have sharepoint 2013 installed and central admin. works fine. I created New Webapplication -> New site collection. but when I try to open it, it does not work, just gives me a message in Norwegian which translates as "**Website coming soon! come back soon to see if website is available**" 
I have correct URL, registered in Dns, App pool and website in IIS looks fine as well. Not sure whats going on!

Answer (score 0):

Hei, I found the reason! The URL that I chose 'Randomly' for my site was an actual web URL of a site under construction! And since my server was connected to internet so it went to the webURL instead!